# VS code. build in terminal command 'open file.html' opens file in browser instead of vs code redactor

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, terminal

how to setup vs code so it opens files in its own redactor? It worked fine but somehow it broke down and now it opens html files in browser by default.

After terminal command 'open fileName' file opens in vs code redactor window.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm here trying to help you. if i'm not mistaken, i'm guessing that you are using MacOS right?

Since i'm using Windows 11, i dont know anything about MacOS, but usually i open VScode via terminal `(Command Prompt / CMD)` then i go to a folder path and use command `code .` in there.

So the VScode open and i can see my `.html` file and other files in that folder in the VScode.

And also i believe that in MacOS it is also possible to set by default what app is used to open certain files such as `.html` file. [In the Windows 11, i can changed it by using the "open file with" feature as shown in this link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hw1l.png). I can choose the VScode option, so it open VScode by default when i click the `.html` file and not open browser.

I also have some references that might help you:

- https://youtu.be/YxJXIPebqMI
- https://youtu.be/xLY6fqT2fIU

Sorry for my bad English, this is all I can give. I hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you, not exactly what I was looking for, but I used recommendations from the second video and now I can run files in vs code with the command <code file.name> instead of <open file.name>.